# SO_NOSIGPIPE was not declared

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am trying to use SO_NOSIGPIPE in a tcp socket.

```
  int set = 1;
  setsockopt(sockDesc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_NOSIGPIPE, (void *)&set, sizeof(int);
```

but an error is coming:

```
   error: SO_NOSIGPIPE was not declared in this scope
```

Is there any header files required, to use that. I have searched over the Internet but didn't get any useful solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent SIGPIPEs (or handle them properly)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108183/how-to-prevent-sigpipes-or-handle-them-properly)

Comment: It's not a standard option, you need to find another way yo handle (or ignore) the signal. For a list of all standard options, see e.g. [this reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_10_16).

Comment: Maybe this does help you? http://stackoverflow.com/q/17682349/2003898

Answer (score 27):

There is no `SO_NOSIGPIPE` in Linux (nor some other systems).  You can instead use the `MSG_NOSIGNAL` flag when calling `send()`, or use `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)` to make your entire application ignore `SIGPIPE`.

Comment: I  Include <signal.h> and used signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN) and it worked for me. thank you.